# how to access dictionary under a dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

`example suppose this is a json dictionary-

how to make this into the dictionary shown below anybody there

```
dictionary={
"actions": [
{
"action_type": "comment",
 "value": "1"
},
{
"action_type": "like",
"value": "18"
},
{
"action_type": "post",
"value": "4"
},
{
"action_type": "post_reaction",
 "value": "268"
},
{
"action_type": "video_view",
"value": "198245"
},
{
"action_type": "page_engagement",
"value": "198536"
},
{
"action_type": "post_engagement",
"value": "198518"
}
],
"date_start": "2018-03-30",
"date_stop": "2018-03-30"
}
```

how can i get this into this i tried the iterator, making function and other method but i am stuck now

```
dictionary={
"comment": "1"
"like": "18"
"post": "4"
"post_reaction": "268"
"video_view": "198245"
"page_engagement": "198536"
"post_engagement": "198518"
"date_start": "2018-03-30",
"date_stop": "2018-03-30"
}`
```

Comment: Please add your code to show what you've tried.

Comment: We can't fix your code if you don't share it.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the `action` key and create the required output:

**Ex:**

```
d = {}
for i in data["actions"]:
    d[i["action_type"]] = i["value"] 

d.update({"date_start": data["date_start"], "date_stop": data["date_start"]})
print(d)
```

Or a **Dict comprehension**

```
print dict((i["action_type"], i["value"]) for i in data["actions"])
```

**Output:**

```
{'comment': '1', 'date_stop': '2018-03-30', 'like': '18', 'date_start': '2018-03-30', 'post_engagement': '198518', 'page_engagement': '198536', 'video_view': '198245', 'post_reaction': '268', 'post': '4'}
```

Comment: Hi !! It Really Help and worked but mine in facebookads.api.Cursor.  and i can't iterate it . so any idea how to use for loop for facebookads.api.Cursor in this

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by iterating over the whole dictionary. If the the type is a list, you should iterate over this list. Doing so will also allow other dictionaries with a similar layout (either lists of other dictionaries or strings) to be handled by the same routine.

```
output_dict = {}
#for key, value in input_dict.items(): python 3
for key, value in input_dict.iteritems(): # python 2
      if type(value) == list:
            for item in value:
                  for key2 in item:
                        if key2 != 'value':
                              output_dict[item[key2]] = item['value']
      else:
            output_dict[key] = value
```

This outputs:

```
{'comment': '1',
 'date_start': '2018-03-30',
 'date_stop': '2018-03-30',
 'like': '18',
 'page_engagement': '198536',
 'post': '4',
 'post_engagement': '198518',
 'post_reaction': '268',
 'video_view': '198245'}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try** 
Use iteritems() and check value is a list or not

```
res = {}
for key,value in dict.iteritems():
if isinstance(value,list):
    for item in value:
        res[item['action_type']] = item['value']
else:
    res[key] = value
```

**Output:**

```
{'comment': '1',
 'date_start': '2018-03-30',
 'date_stop': '2018-03-30',
 'like': '18',
 'page_engagement': '198536',
 'post': '4',
 'post_engagement': '198518',
 'post_reaction': '268',
 'video_view': '198245'}
```